# How to install R on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I just bought a new machine and made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 21.10 since I've read that the newer kernel works better with graphics drivers. I'm planning to update to the 22.04 LTS when it will be available. I didn't realize, however, that I might run into challenges with R.

There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67849719/installing-r-on-ubuntu-20-04) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597054/best-way-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04) here in SO on installing R on Ubuntu, but none seemed recent enough to address the Ubuntu version 21.10.

[Ubuntu Packages For R - Full Instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html) state that

> As of May 19, 2021 the supported releases are
>
> - Hirsute Hippo (21.04, amd64 only)
> - Groovy Gorilla (20.10, amd64 only),
> - Focal Fossa (20.04; LTS and amd64 only),
> - Bionic Beaver (18.04; LTS), and
> - Xenial Xerus (16.04; LTS).

So, if I understand correctly, I have three options:

1. Uninstall 21.10 and replace with 21.04
2. Wait for support for 21.10
3. Install R from source

Now, the question is, have I understood correctly, or **could I use, for example, the 21.04 repository** (`hirsute-cran40/`)?

Comment: So did you try to install it and run into problems or are you worried it might not work? Also not a programming question, you get more suited answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I haven't tried, I'm worried it might not work, especially if I later want to upgrade Ubuntu to the next LTS.. maybe I should just try and hope. For the forum, I was first thinking of Ask Ubuntu but I thought this more of an R issue, and there are a lot of similar questions here.

Comment: Honestly I don’t see any issue at all. If you’re worried and don’t find answers test it yourself in a virtual machine. I bet it’ll work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is ok to use a repository of older releases.

I was encouraged by Andre Wildeberg (thanks!) and added the 21.04 repository (`hirsute-cran40/`) into my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu hirsute-cran40/
```

Then, you can follow the rest of the [CRAN instructions](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html).

Add the relevant GPG key (under "Secure APT", half way through the document):

```
$ wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
```

Finally, install R:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install r-base
```

And everything should be working fine.

Comment: As commented below you do not need to go a randon Digital Ocean write-up, The hint is also in [this fullREADME on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/fullREADME.html) and its mirrors under the _Secure APT_ section.  Might be nice if you could edit your answer again.

Comment: I edited the answer to include a reference to the "Secure APT" section for adding the GPG key.

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer signing key for that repo:

```
root:~#  apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.MsSJzqgwfx/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" 1 new signature
gpg: failed to start agent '/usr/bin/gpg-agent': No such file or directory
gpg: can't connect to the agent: No such file or directory
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 1
root:~# apt update
Get:1 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu hirsute-cran40/ InRelease [3628 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                  
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Fetched 325 kB in 1s (422 kB/s)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
root:#
```

One you have that, impish works fine.  That said, hirsute binaries should work too (or even focal binaries, as one does with the 5000+ `r-cran-*` binaries the 'cran2deb4ubuntu' repo for the LTS release).

Comment: I fixed a copu/paste typo in my Answer in the Digital Ocean example of adding the GPG key (instead of `sudo apt-key..`, I had copy/pasted the url). And yes, Impish seems to work fine on Hirsuite binaries.

Comment: I spoke with Michael, the hint is also on the 'fuller README' but somehow did not get sync'ed to the main repo.  We're looking into it.